# get name of object in array when option.amount equals zero

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an array of names of objects that have options.amount all equals to zero. Thanks for your time. This is what i tryed:

```js
let variants = [        
        {
            name: 'extra',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'meat',
                    price: 3,
                    amount: 0
                },
                {
                    name: 'cheese',
                    price: 1,
                    amount: 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'sauce',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'ketchup',
                    price: 2,
                    amount: 1
                },
                {
                    name: 'mayo',
                    price: 1,
                    amount: 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

//Expected output = ['extra']

let arrayOfOptionsNames = variants.map(x => x.options.filter(y => y.amount === 0 ? x.name : 0))
console.log(arrayOfOptionsNames)
```

Comment: Related to your question, but you can take this with you for other things: Maybe you could consider coding your functions in a more descriptive way, before moving/refactoring it to a one-liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.every()` method to get your result. `Every` method test if every elements of the array pass the test by the given callback function and returns a boolean value.

```js
const variants = [
  {
    name: 'extra',
    options: [
      {
        name: 'meat',
        price: 3,
        amount: 0,
      },
      {
        name: 'cheese',
        price: 1,
        amount: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'sauce',
    options: [
      {
        name: 'ketchup',
        price: 2,
        amount: 1,
      },
      {
        name: 'mayo',
        price: 1,
        amount: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
];
const ret = variants
  .filter((x) => x.options.every((y) => y.amount === 0))
  .map((x) => x.name);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thanks mr hr, every() method it's what i need

Answer (score 3):

You could filter and get the wanted property.

```js
let variants = [{ name: 'extra', options: [{ name: 'meat', price: 3, amount: 0 }, { name: 'cheese', price: 1, amount: 0 }] }, { name: 'sauce', options: [{ name: 'ketchup', price: 2, amount: 1 }, { name: 'mayo', price: 1, amount: 0 }] }],
    result = variants
        .filter(({ options }) => options.every(({ amount }) => !amount))
        .map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(result);
```